# How to put async task returned values into variables (global?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, geolocation, google-geolocation

I have to use google (or similar) geocode APIs to obtain information (state, country, address) by latitude and longitude.

I've googled a lot and I've found some useful code, but this code puts information in an alert box.

I've found tips about **callback functions**...

I need to use "state" or "Country" outside the async task (for example in the HTML page when I press a button).

I've tried to create a global variable (*actArea*), but, after  **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition** call, its value is "*EMPTY*".
This is, I think, right, because the Async Task is *async* but how can I save the Async Task result into a global variable or similar?

Why the **callback** isn't working?
Where is the mistake?

I've tried also using **setTimeout**, but with the same results.

Thanks.

This a part of my code (*geodec.js*):

```
var x = document.getElementById("destination_div");

var actLatPos = 45.076947;
var actLonPos = 7.614174;
var actArea = 'EMPTY';

function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);

        //actArea returns "EMPTY"
        alert(actArea);

    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

}

function retrieveGPSdata(data)
{
    actArea=data.results[0].address_components[5].long_name;

    //actArea returns "Piemonte"
    alert(actArea);

    $('#destination_div').text( "Latitude: " + actLatPos + " Longitude: " + actLonPos + " Area: " + actArea);
}
function showPosition(position) {
    var richiesta='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + actLatPos + ',' +  actLonPos + '&sensor=true';

    //setTimeout(function()
    //{
        $.ajax({ url:richiesta, success:retrieveGPSdata});
    //},8000);

}
```

Comment: this code is working fine
Latitude: 45.076947 Longitude: 7.614174 Area: Piedmont

Comment: @Alex but not outside the async task. I would like to use "Piedmont" also in the other parts of my app. My app needs to localize the user on startup and send localized info to the user every time he press a button.

Comment: I think the important part here is 'async'. Looks like you're just accessing the actArea before the asynchronous task has completed.

Comment: @jamesk yes, it is. But I don't know to wait the end of the task...but the task is asyncronous... It sounds like: what was before: the egg or the chicken?

Comment: @MassimoCostanzo but that's the point of the callback (retrieveGPSdata), it tells you when the server call has completed. If you have other features (you mentioned a button) that need the value, then they should probably be disabled until your callback completes.

Comment: @jamesk ok, that's true, but how can I tell to the button that the server has completed the request?

Comment: @MassimoCostanzo ok take a look at [this example](http://liveweave.com/vARywi). Async calls aren't about scoping (things aren't in or outside them), they're about timing. If you want more explanation then let me know.

Comment: @jamesk Great! With Firefox your code works fine (thanks), but with Safari (Mac) it's not working

Comment: @MassimoCostanzo define 'not working' :) Just tried on Safari on my MB and it was fine. Anything showing up in the JS console?

Comment: @jamesk in the JS console on Safari (in my MBP) nothing happens after pressing the first button, but in Firefox in works. In Safary for iOS it works.

Comment: @MassimoCostanzo sounds like you have location settings disabled perhaps then, it's something the user normally has to approve (at least once). Also a quick google points to potential issues around Safari versions and wifi?

Comment: @jamesk Location services are enabled and I'm using a LAN, not a WiFi. The first time I run your example in Safari, I approve the use of location services, but Safari shows me the alert(err.message)...empty. On Firefox everything is ok...on Safari for iOS everything is ok except the title of the "area" alert ("about://(null)

Comment: @MassimoCostanzo it's going to be difficult to debug via proxy on this ;) Try replacing the `alert(err.message)` with a `console.dir(err)` and see what comes out. It's pretty simplistic code and with it working on other browsers (inc. Safari on my MBP) there must just be something weird happening with that setup.